# Issues using html popups with QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, html, maptips

I was happily using html popups with QGIS 2.8.3 for various things including a showing a photo. However, I've updated to 2.18 to take advantage of other new functionalities, and now find that my html popup will no longer show the photo the way it used to.

This is the html I'm trying to use:

```
<img src="Camera/[%PHOTO_1%]" width=150>
```

The image name is in field PHOTO_1 and the image is in a subfolder named Camera (subfolder on same level as qgis project).

With version 2.8.3, the html provided showed the photo. With version 2.18, I only have a blank popup.

I've now tried it two additional ways without success:

```
<img src= "@project_folder + '/Camera/' + [%PHOTO_1%]>
```

and

```
<img src= [% @project_folder + '/Camera/' + "PHOTO_1"%]>
```

Comment: see similar post: [how do I view geotagged photos and audio points in qgis mac?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239367/how-do-i-view-geotagged-photos-and-audio-points-in-qgis-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<img src= [% @project_folder + '/Camera/' + "PHOTO_1" %] alt= "My_Photo_1" width= 150/>
```

Nothing special, however;

- Remove double quotation marks around `[% %]` ...... (this is confusing... a bug?)
- Use full-path. project variables may help.

Comment: I can't seem to get your example to work. How come we should put the project_folder variable and '/Camera/' within the field name brackets [% %]?

Comment: @user25976 It is because your project file (.qgis) and the photos are separated, as in your Camera folder. The important point is to use Full-path. `@project_folder` variables helps us to shorten the path.

Comment: Sorry to be a broken record, but it's still a no-go. To be clear, the field 'PHOTO_1' contains only the file name e.g. '20170403.jpg'. It is just in the html specification that the '@project_folder' variable is called. Seems right to you?

Comment: It looks fine to me the field "PHOTO_1" but are you sure you put it in single quote? It should be in double quote mark (" "). Or if @project_folder variable does not work, please start with simple absolute path such as  [% 'C:/your_path_to_Camera_folder/' + "PHOTO_1" %] and see if it works.